# Environment variables in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am developing a plugin to deploy my application in pre-integration-phase in maven. Now when the application boots up and all beans are created, then inside a setter method a env variable is passed whose value is fetched.

```
public void setEnvName(final String passwordEnvName) {
    super.setPassword(System.getenv(passwordEnvName));
}
```

Usage being

```
<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="PRIVATE_KEY" />
</bean>
```

Now i cannot set this variable in unix boxes. I tried the following

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <exec executable="env">
                        <env key="PRIVATE_KEY" value="PASSWORD_KEY"/>
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but it always comes as null. Is there way any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You cannot set an environement property, whether in Ant or Maven or anything. This is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Maven is only executed at build time, not at runtime.
So even if you set the env variable when you build, at runtime it will be empty if :

- the program runs on another system than it was build
- the env var was not set permanently, but only for the current process, so when it ends the env var is gone.